# Compiling app to browser or android and showing old code

Tags: android, cordova, browser, device, ripple

When I build my Cordova app sometimes the correct HTML and CSS is displayed but other times I'm missing entire HTML blocks and css files. I've tried building multiple times and running on Browser/Device but it still shows the old app. I've also tried deleting the platforms folders re-adding the platforms and then building but still no luck.

Anyone had this issue and know how to solve it?

Comment: No probamos! Be sure to accept my answer as the correct answer. This gives a big 'ol checkmark for other people to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Empty the browser cache and then restart the browser.